# how to use `issubset` for dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary `A`, and list `B`. I want to get key from `A` dictionary if `B` is `subset A.values()` ?

```
A={1: 'jendela', 2: 'jendela', 3: 'kursi', 4: 'meja', 5: 'pintu', 6: 'payung'}
B=set(['jendela','kursi'])
c=[[1,3],[2,3]]

>> B.issubset(A.values())
>> True
```

But how i get list `C`. `C` is output example if I have dictionary `A` and list `B`

Comment: Please clarify your question as it is unclear right now what you want to get using `c`. I'm guessing you want to check/get values from `A` based on the elements of `c` (and matching keys)?

Comment: I want to get key from `A` using list `B`. 'C' is output example that I want if I have `A` and `B`

Comment: I do not understand the desired output. Why `[1,3],[2,3]`?? I know 1, 2 and 3 are the keys, but why grouped that way?

Comment: C has : [1 is key of `jendela`, 2 is key of `kursi`],[2 is key of `jendela`, 3 is key of `kursi`]. `Jendela` and `kursi` are items of 'B'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the to produce a list of all sets of keys into dictionary `A` that will lookup all the values in your set `B`.

The first thing you need is to a listing of the keys for each value you need. For that, I think you really want to reverse your `A` mapping. Instead of mapping from a number to a string, map from a string to a list of numbers:

```
A = {1: 'jendela', 2: 'jendela', 3: 'kursi', 4: 'meja', 5: 'pintu', 6: 'payung'}

A_reversed = collections.defaultdict(list)
for number, string in A.items():
    A_reversed[string].append(number)
```

Now, use `itertools.product` to combine the required lists together:

```
result_gen = itertools.product(*(A_reversed[string] for string in B))
```

This result is a generator, if you need a list, use `list(result_gen)` (or just include a `list` call in the line above).

If one of the values from `B` doesn't appear as a value in `A`,  you'll get empty results.